# Scala - Get type of class member

Tags: scala, types

I need to get class' name and type.

I tried with this code.

```
  case class test( name: String, num: Int, types: String)

  ru.typeOf[ test].members.foreach { x =>
      if( !x.isMethod)
      {
          println( x + " => " + x.name + " / " + x.typeSignature) 
          if( x.typeSignature == scala.Int) {

          }
          //if( x.typeSignature == java.lang.String) { // object java.lang.String is not a value

          //}
      }
  }
```

> result
>
> value types => types  / String
>
> value num => num  / scala.Int
>
> value name => name  / String

I can get all name and types but cannot give condition with type because of String type's value. Any Idea of this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `typeOf` to get the `String` type, like:

```
x.typeSignature =:= typeOf[String]
```

> `=:=` is used to see if both denote the exact same compile-time type. http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html

For your compare `Int`, you should also compare like the `x.typeSignature =:= typeOf[Int]`, compare `scala.Int` directly, you will get the below warning:

```
<console>:18: warning: reflect.runtime.universe.Type and Int.type are unrelated: they will most likely never compare equal
       res23.typeSignature == scala.Int
```

Comment: I got "not found: value typeOf" error. Should I import some package?

Comment: @J.Done, for your code example, you should use `ru.typeOf[String]`

Comment: or you can `import ru._`